# Yii2 delete() without primary key

Tags: php, database, yii2

I want to delete a data in database with `delete`, but the table doesn't have the primary key

Here's the code

```
Table::findOne(['name' => 'Andrew', 'Age' => '25'])->delete();
```

Then, it shows the error

```
app\models\Table does not have a primary key. You should either define a primary key for the corresponding table or override the primaryKey() method.
```

Help me to find the way to delete without a primary key.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried either of the two suggestions in the error message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could override primaryKey() model method, so the error should disappear.

Inside **app\models\Table** add this method (I think that primary key should be composed with 'name' and 'Age'):

```
public static function primaryKey()
{
  return [
     'name',
     'Age',
  ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. It works.. But, can i use this method for update the data, too?

Comment: exactly, but you should declare your primary key directly in db table.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using ActiveRecord, you  could use a delete command  with condition:

```
 $myCommand =  Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
              ->delete('your_table', 'name =  "Andrew"  AND Age = 25  ');

 $myCommand->execute();
```

If you want to delete all the rows that match the condition, you can use:

```
  deleteAll( ... ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
$data=Table::find()->where(['name' => 'Andrew', 'Age' => '25'])->one();
$data->delete();
```